# Viewing checkedstatus of checkbox in external application VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, sendmessage

Building a tool to automate interactions with the front end interface of a massive database. Many fields are modified by toggling a checkbox between checked and unchecked and hitting save. There is no way to get into the database itself to either make updates directly or to view settings, everything has to go through the front-end application.

Checking the box is no trouble at all, just a simple `Sendmessage(hndl, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)` but the problem is that this just toggles the box. I need to ensure that it is checked, and if I send the click on an already checked box, it will uncheck it.

I've tried using `BM_SETCHECK` to force a checked status but it has no effect. I've also tried using both `BM_GETCHECK` and `BM_GETSTATE` to tell whether the box is already checked before sending my BM_CLICK command. Unfortunately the function I created to check the status always returns false.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports vb = Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class ucCheckBoxChecker

Private Const BM_CLICK As Integer = &HF5
Private Const BST_CHECKED As Integer = &H1
Private Const BM_GETSTATE As Integer = &HF2

Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, _
ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

Private Declare Function SendMessageA Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, _
ByVal lParam As String) As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim hndlCheckBox As Integer = FindWindowEx(hndlParent, 0, "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r11_ad1", vbNullString)

    If IsChecked(hndlCheckBox) = False Then SendMessageA(hndlCheckBox, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)

End Sub

Public Function IsChecked(ByVal hWnd As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim intHndlVal As Integer
    intHndlVal = SendMessage(hWnd, BM_GETSTATE, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print(intHndlVal)
    IsChecked = ((intHndlVal And BST_CHECKED) = BST_CHECKED)

End Function

End Class
```

I've verified that the handles are correct, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get `intHndlVal` to be anything other than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the AutomationElement class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750424(v=vs.110).aspx

The code below is c# but you should be able to use an online code converter to convert to vb .net.  I took the IsElementToggledOn code from one of the websites listed above.

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle( hwnd );

/// <summary> 
/// Gets the toggle state of an element in the target application. 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="element">The target element.</param>
private bool IsElementToggledOn(AutomationElement element)
{
    if (element == null)
    {
        // TODO: Invalid parameter error handling. 
        return false;
    }

    Object objPattern;
    TogglePattern togPattern;
    if (true == element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern, out objPattern))
    {
        togPattern = objPattern as TogglePattern;
        return togPattern.Current.ToggleState == ToggleState.On;
    }
    // TODO: Object doesn't support TogglePattern error handling. 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It took some doing, (and a ton of googling) but the AutomationElement approach seems to be working. Will actually be going back and rewriting some of the API commands to use AutomationElements, as it's a more versatile way of interacting with external application.